# Password protect uninstallation of Firefox Addon using SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Background to this problem: Within out company we are working on an add-on to help us do some nifty things. To make it easier to administer we would like to have a password required to at minimum remove the add-on, but probably also to disable it.

I've seen this achieved in for example [Public Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/public-fox/?src=search) but this is non-sdk style add-on. So my question is if there's an easy way to do this using the SDK? I've looked through the docs but I haven't found anything, probably because I don't know what I'm looking for.

To anticipate the question "why not use that add-on as well?" I think it's enough of a hassle to make sure everyone has one add-on installed, let alone two.

Comment: A user who can really remove the extension can always remove the corresponding directory from his profile.

Comment: @WladimirPalant I was hoping you would join in :) That is true of course, but I don't think the majority of the users will be able to figure that out. This is (as many other things) a question from management so I'm just trying to find the feasibility in this.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/01/922449.aspx :)

Comment: Point taken (and on a personal level I agree). I'll see if I can't talk everyone out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to lock users down, what you're really looking for is a deployment technique where your Firefox deployment installs your extension by default, and to an area of the hard drive that the user does not have write/delete access to. See the Mozilla Wiki for more details on ESR builds and enterprise deployments:

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Deployment:Deploying_Firefox#Firefox_Customization_.28CCK_and_Repackaging_Tools.29

Comment: You are right. That is what we should do if we go down that path.

Comment: That's what I was also thinking but from what I remember the user can still disable the extension.